# gsub allowing double quotations inside gsub

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, gsub

I have this

```
self.description.gsub! 'iframe', 'iframe id="myid" '
```

And it outputs this when I save:

```
iframe id=\"myid\"
```

But I don't want the backslashes \ before each "

How do I do this?

How do I allow 2 x " inside?

Comment: There are no backslashes in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you are running it inside IRB, but sometimes you have to print to see how the string looks like:

```
tiago@lenovo:~$ irb
2.3.0 :001 > str = "frame"
 => "frame" 
2.3.0 :002 > str.gsub('frame','iframe id="myid"')
 => "iframe id=\"myid\"" 
2.3.0 :003 > puts str.gsub('frame','iframe id="myid"')
iframe id="myid"
 => nil
```

Note that the returned value of gsub is escaping double quotes but that's because the whole string is wrapped by double quotes, the value printed is different though.

Comment: Also, `p string` is equivalent to `puts string.inspect`, and inspect shows string with `"\""`

Comment: Thanks! Turns out the wysiwyg editor I'm using (Froala) has a js sanitizer, that even though I did the above, still throws \ in front of all quotation-marks. Pain in the ass. But your answer is correct still, thanks.